# Does Microsoft Graph API work with Office 365 family subscription?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365

having an Office 365 family subscription, I'd like to use Microsoft Graph to query certain data from Outlook (events) and To-Do from within a web application.

Having had a look at the microsoft tutorials/quick start sessions, it seems that I have to register my application first to receive an access token.

Though, loggin in into Azure Portal with my personal Outlook account (with the O365 family subscription) I can not register an app/receive an token.

Am I missing something, or is Microsoft Graph only useable for business/educational subscriptions which are allowed to use Azure AD?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this article help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70392637/microsoft-graph-api-does-not-return-all-received-mail-for-family-and-personal-ac

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:-***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/use-your-free-azure-ad-subscription-in-office-365?view=o365-worldwide)

> ***Microsoft Azure Active Directory is free if your organisation has a
> paid subscription to Microsoft 365, Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online,
> Enterprise Mobility Suite, or other Microsoft services. Azure AD
> allows you and other administrators to create and manage user and
> group accounts.***

For more information please refer this **MS Q&A**|[***Invalid grant error for free Office 365 Family & Personal/Free accounts***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/203068/invalid-grant-error-for-free-office-365-family-amp.html).